# Will eggs absorb flavor from cooking liquid?

Tags: eggs, soup

Making scrambled eggs by boiling them seems all the rage these days. I tried it with mixed results; there seems to be a bit of a knack.

I’d like to know, if I use a liquid other than water, like stock or dashi, will the eggs absorb any of the flavor from the liquid?

Comment: I would assume so, unless you're cooking your eggs in a plastic bag in the boiling liquid.  But that's just a guess.

Comment: To anybody who wants to answer: please note the technique. This question is not asking about eggs boiled in their shells.

Comment: There are multiple ways to solve the shell barrier. One option is to break the shell when the egg is lightly cooked (so that the shell breaks but the egg doesn't lose its shape), which gives you a very interesting pattern on the egg as a bonus. Or you can peel the egg completely and let it continue cooking without the shell. Additionally soaking the egg in the liquid helps a lot, too, even if the liquid is cold, given enough time, salt will penetrate.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's pretty clear that eggs absorb flavors that they are soaked in. Just look at [these pictures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Century_egg) and decide for yourself. These are soy sauce eggs, but eggs can be soaked in anything and readily absorb that liquid and associated flavors. The brown color is not the shell but soy sauce:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A question good to answer after eastern :D

Yes, the eggs will get some of the flavour. To be exact they will absorb flavoured fat into their first layer. 
Of course if the eggs is properly been the absorption level will be higher as egg white is quite resistant to flavouring while yolk take it like sponge.

To get taste similar to eggs made on a pan use melted butter with water. I think that broth would have too strong taste and would dominate the dish.